# How to add the link with image slider in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I make a Image slider but now i want to add the link on every image.

```
(function(){
 var srcs = [
"/images/options/family_4.jpg",
"/images/options/family_5.jpg",
"/images/options/family_3.jpg"
];
var links = [
"http://google.com",
"http://youtube.com",
"http://yahoo.com"
];

var currentIndex = srcs.length-1;
var changeBanner = function(){
    if(currentIndex == 0){
        da.jQuery(".banner-fade-img").fadeIn();
        currentIndex = srcs.length-1;
    } else {
        da.jQuery(da.jQuery(".banner-fade-img").get(currentIndex)).fadeOut();
        currentIndex--;
    }
}

var bannerSetup = function(){
_.each(srcs, function(src, index){
    da.jQuery(".image-container").append("<img class='banner-fade-img' style='top:0px;position:absolute; z-index:"+(index+2)+";' src=' "+src+"'></img>");

})
window.setInterval(changeBanner, 5000);
}

bannerSetup();
}())
```

I make two array but i don't know how to add the second array with image..Please help me...How to fix it?

Comment: I don't see anchor tags in your code. What have you tried?

Comment: i want to add link on each image.

Comment: Do you want to add links to each image ?  Can you explain with an example that is html ?

Comment: ok ...... I want to <a href="http://google.com"><img src="abc.jsp"></a>

Comment: I have three images and three links and i want to add the one by one link on each image in jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not combine the image `src`, and the a `href` in one Array literal? It would be much easier, and you could do something like so:

```
(function(){
    var datas = [
        {
            'image': "http://i.imgur.com/1fWTOIj.png",
            'url': "http://google.com",
        },
        {
            'image': "http://i.imgur.com/AhWrnN4.gif",
            'url': "http://youtube.com",
        },
    ]

    var currentIndex = datas.length-1;
        changeBanner = function(){
            if(currentIndex == 0){
                $(".banner-fade-img").fadeIn();
                currentIndex = datas.length-1;
            } else {
                $($(".banner-fade-img").get(currentIndex)).fadeOut();
                currentIndex--;
            }
        }
    console.log(currentIndex);

    var bannerSetup = function(){
        $.each(datas, function(index, src) {
            $(".image-container").append(
                '<a href="' + src.url + '">'
            +'<img class="banner-fade-img" width="150" height="150" src="' + src.image + '">'
                +'</a>'
            );
        })
        window.setInterval(changeBanner, 5000);
    }

    bannerSetup();
}())
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alleks/X6sfv/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm taking a wild guess..Try this

```
append("<a href='"+links[index]+"' ><img class='banner-fade-img' style='top:0px;position:absolute; z-index:"+(index+2)+";' src=' "+src+"'></img></a>");
```